# Randomly sample from a dataset then delete sampled entries (R)

Tags: r, random

I have random sample of 600 elements from the normal distribtion stored in a vector:

```
sample_data <- rnorm(600, mean =10, sd = 6)
```

I am trying to split this vector into 100 random groups of 6 entries each.
Doing this once is a simple proposition with the sample function:

```
group_1 <- sample(6, sample_data, replace=FALSE)
```

However, if I use the sample function again there is a chance some of the entries will be re-used because they weren't deleted from the initial data.  A possible solution might be to initially store the data in a 100x6 matrix and consider each row as a "random group."

However, I am curious if there is a more efficient method to take consecutive samples from a dataset while ensuring no entry is sampled more than once.
Thanks!

Comment: @Pascal - `matrix(sample(sample_data), 6, 100)` would scramble the cases as well.

Comment: Theoretically yes only because the initial sample was randomly generated.  But for argument's sake assume the sample wasn't random.  How could you split it into 100 random groups of 6?

Comment: `matrix(sample_data[sample(1:600, 600)], 6, 100)`

Comment: @jeremycg - no need for the indexing. `sample(1:10)` for instance will just scramble without replacement the original `1:10`

Answer (score 0):

Let `g` be a vector assigning each index 1..600 to a group, 1..100. We'll start with

```
g0 = rep(1:100, each=6)
# [1]   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2 ...
```

and scramble it

```
set.seed(1)
g = sample(g0)
#   [1]  27  38  58  91  21  90  94  66  ...
```

Now, if you want to split your original vector up, use `split`:

```
split(sample_data, g)
# $`1`
# [1] 18.528965  7.463326  7.585449  5.701404  2.017379 10.866809
# 
# $`2`
# [1]  6.338364 22.112578  5.370649  9.952592 10.618581  1.168506
# ...
```

As pointed out by several commenters, it makes sense to store this in a matrix. It'll be much faster and all-around simpler to work with:

```
sample_mat <- matrix(sample_data[order(g)], 100, 6, byrow=TRUE)
#           [,1]      [,2]     [,3]     [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
# [1,] 18.528965  7.463326 7.585449 5.701404  2.017379 10.866809
# [2,]  6.338364 22.112578 5.370649 9.952592 10.618581  1.168506
# ...
```

I like to construct such a vector, `g`, to keep track of things, but as @thelatemail pointed out in one of the first comments, you can simply do `sample_mat <- matrix(sample(sample_data), 6, 100)`, assigning to groups and putting the result in a matrix in a single step.